# async function is not working in node js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, loopback

I am trying to develop an APP in which I have to increase or decrease the user count according to their hobbies/interest in the master list. I am doing it in Node js with the help of loopback. Here is my code, in which I am giving two interests(i.e sketching and horse-riding):

```
  async.forEach(data, function (interest) {
        console.log("Interest is", interest);

        Interest.findOne({
            where:
            {
                'name': interest
            }
        }, function (err, interestObj) {
            if (err) {
                //return callback(err, null);
                console.log("error", err);
            }
            else {
                //return callback(null, response);
                console.log("found", interestObj);
                if (!interestObj) {
                    Interest.create({ "name": interest, "count": 1 }, function (err, response) { });

                }
                else {
                    _count = interestObj.count + 1;
                    interestObj.updateAttribute('count', _count, function (e, r) { });
                }
            }
        });

      //  return callback(null, {});
    },function(err){
        console.log("success..!!")
    });
}
```

but it is showing me only one of them in output. Here is output:

```
    data is [ 'horse-riding', 'skeching' ]
Interest is horse-riding
Interest is skeching
found { name: 'horse-riding', count: 1, id: 59ccff0765055a212491a6bc }
found null
```

I think the async function is not working properly with forEach loop in this, But I am not getting where the code went wrong. I want to show all the interest given by the user, so what course of actions should I take to do it?? Thanks in advance..!!:)

Comment: does the interest "sketching" already exist in db? It seems like it may not.

Comment: Typo maybe? You have 'skeching' in data and probably 'sketching' in the db

Comment: @ zillaofthegods: Even the horse-riding was not there in the master list, still, it will create a new interest with count one. But this case is not applicable for sketching.  I run this code multiple times and it gives me output almost (n-1) time. Like If I gave 5 interests it only print 4 in many cases

Comment: @Yury: Purposefully I give 'skeching', instead of 'sketching'. Cause I want to show as it is that whatever user gives as an interest. If the interest already exists in master list then it should have to increase the count by one, and if not create a new one

Comment: It is working now...!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is working now...!!!

```
  async.each(data, function (interest, callback2) {
        console.log('Processing ', interest);
        Interest.findOne({
            where:
            {
                'name': interest
            }
        }, function (err, interestObj) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error", err);
                callback2(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("found", interestObj);
                if (!interestObj) {
                    Interest.create({ "name": interest, "count": 1 }, function (err, response) { });
                }
                else {
                    _count = interestObj.count + 1;
                    interestObj.updateAttribute('count', _count, function (e, r) { });
                }
                callback2();
            }
        });
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failed to process', err);
        } else {
            console.log('All interests have been processed successfully');
        }
        return callback(err);
    })
};
```